# Twitter Authentication on Swift and SafariServices.framework

Tags: swift, xcode, twitter-oauth

I am trying to implment Twitter authentication on my Swift based app by following the doc https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/log-in-with-twitter

At the "Prerequisites" Section:

> 3.Add *SafariServices.framework* to use *SFSafariViewController*.

My understanding is, it will use Safari in my App to register or login with Twitter, if the Twitter App is not installed.

However, what I don't understand is:

1. If I add the following to my ViewController, meaning the same as SafariServices.framework?

   > import SafariServices
2. What does it exactly mean by

   > "to use *SFSafariViewController*"?

Do I need to add additional inheritance in my ViewController class?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in IOS 11 and xCode 9, you can safely ignore this step.

Without importing SafariServices and inheritance additional views in the class, twitter button is able to handle calling safari for register/login.